# Extract multiple tags from within a tag

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

thanks in advance for any help you can provide. I'm trying to scrape some HTML with HtmlAgilityPack and am having trouble with the XPATH syntax. The HTML I'm dealing with has multiple tags I'd like to access all within a < p >.

```
<p class="row" data-pid="5687754180">
    <a href="/bod/5687754180.html" class="i gallery" data-ids="1:00c0c_fapkFsQg3Dx">
        <span class="price">$5000</span>
    </a>
    <span class="txt">
        <span class="pl">
            <span class="icon icon-star" role="button">
                <span class="screen-reader-text">
                    <? __("favorite this post") ?>
                </span>
            </span>
            <time datetime="2016-07-17 19:36" title="Sun 17 Jul 07:36:03 PM">Jul 17</time> <a href="/bod/5687754180.html" data-id="5687754180" class="hdrlnk">
                <span id="titletextonly">&#9735;&#9735;&#9812;&#9812;&#9812;&#9812;&#9812;1998 Mastercraft Prostar&#12963</span>
            </a>
        </span>
        <span class="l2">
            <span class="price">$5000</span>
            <span class="pnr">
                <span class="px">
                    <span class="p"> pic</span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="js-only banish-unbanish">
            <span class="banish">
                <span class="icon icon-trash" role="button"/>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">hide this posting</span>
            </span>
            <span class="unbanish">
                <span class="icon icon-trash red" role="button"/> restore this posting</span>
        </span>
    </span>
</p>
```

My thought was that I could iterate over all the < p > tags and get the tags within each that I needed, but it's not working out so well. Here's what I would like to get:

[image]

and then move on to the next < p > and get the same thing.  I feel like I'm getting close, but am missing something crucial. For example, this snippet gets me the "data-pid" from each

, but the "titletextonly" is same one over and over.

[image] 
[image]

Thanks for any help you can provide!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever your XPath starts with `/`, it will always be treated as absolute XPath (in other words, relative to the root document) ignoring current context element, which in this case is referenced by variable `title`. That said, `SelectSingleNode()` will always return the first element in the entire document matched by the XPath parameter, regardless of the context element.

To make the XPath relative to context element, you need to add a `.` at the beginning :

```
var node = title.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@id='titletextonly']");
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!